# How would I add a padding to the plot area in HighCharts (HighStock) to pad the border?

Tags: highcharts

I looked at using margin: and spacing:, but it's not adding the padding I'm looking for.

Design

padded border graph mockup:

[image: screenshot]

Code

```
    chart: {
        type: 'arearange',
        plotBorderColor: '#000000',
        plotBorderWidth: 2,
        margin: [15, 15, 15, 15],
        spacing: [15, 15, 15, 15],
    },
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uk3cbfo/1/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/g26uk3px/

using

```
chart.rangeSelector.buttonTheme.padding: 15
chart.rangeSelector.buttonSpacing: 15
```

References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttonTheme.padding
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/navigation.buttonOptions